# What is the best browser for simulating?

Tags: windows, linux, web-browser

I need a browser that is efficient at calculating sums using Javascript.

#### Things that are required:

- Browser that is fast
- GUI not required
- Runs of Windows/Linux
- Big plus if free

Comment: _Browser that is fast_ - That's a pretty broad requirement.  What do you consider fast?  And, what is it you're trying to "simulate"?

Comment: So you need the browser that executes its Javascript the fastest. I'd google something like "browser javascript benchmarks"

Comment: @rrirower Sorry for not making myself clearer, I meant calculating sums using Javascript - Jan Doggen, thanks for the suggestion =)  I'm googling it now.

Comment: So no GUI required. I don't see why JavaScript is required. As you mention Linux, in Bash calculation is as easy as `echo $((1+2))`. And there are plenty of pure calculator applications available. Some background why it has to be a browser and JavaScript would help finding what you're really after :) While on it, better also update your question's title: "the best" is pretty subjective (and we'd not recomment "the worst" anyhow), plus "simulating" doesn't really match what you describe.

Comment: @Izzy I'm very sorry, I thought those sort of questions were welcome [here](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=What+is+the+best) - What would you suggest I do, delete this question?

Comment: I'd rather thought you could *improve* it. Currently it's pretty unclear what you're after, so *we* are sorry not being able to provide you good answers! Didn't want to "lecture" you: my last comment should just show my confusion and illustrate to you how others might read/understand your post. So my suggestion starts with the 4th sentence ("Some background..."). Would that be an option for you? ;)

Comment: Are you sure you need a browser ? If you just want to run Javascript code you should take a look at Node.js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/).

> PhantomJS is a headless WebKit scriptable with a JavaScript API. It
>   has fast and native support for various web standards: DOM handling,
>   CSS selector, JSON, Canvas, and SVG

PhantomJs is a "headless browser", which will let you concentrate on your JS without having to worry about a GUI.  It is widely used for testing on many FOSS projects.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best browser that is efficient for calculating sums using *Javascript* is **Mozilla**.  It should give **pointers to tools**, **aids and tricks which make debugging your code easier**. To know more about how this browser helps you in stimulating and to work with the Mozilla Firefox, see the article provided by **Mozilla Developer Network** by *visit the given link:*

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Debugging_JavaScript

Comment: I guess you meant "the best browser [...] is **Mozilla Firefox**". "Mozilla" alone is the name of a [community](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozilla), a [foundation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozilla_Foundation) and a [corporation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozilla_Corporation), but you seem to know that since you mentioned Firefox later in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

#### [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/)

HtmlUnit is a "GUI-Less browser for Java programs". It models HTML documents and provides an API that allows you to invoke pages, fill out forms, click links, etc... just like you do in your "normal" browser.

You can use it directly, or use other tools which are based on it. The homepage has links to these.

#### [RhinoUnit](https://code.google.com/p/rhinounit/)

Scripting framework for javascript, runs using the Rhino engine.